# Find the parameter M

Tags: calculus, derivatives

m(x+1)=e^|x| , m is a real number .Find the interval to which the parameter 'm' belongs , so that the previous equation has exactly two different solutions . Any idea how to approach this kind of problems ? Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: I think it should say exactly two real solutions.

Comment: You're partially right , my bad . The text says : 'exacly two different real solutions ' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the derivative:

$$
f(x) = e^{|x|} - m(x + 1) \\
f'(x) = \begin{cases} e^{|x|} - m & x > 0 \\ -e^{|x|} - m & x < 0\end{cases}
$$

This function goes to $+\infty$ at both extremes (i.e. when $x \rightarrow -\infty$ *and* when $x \rightarrow +\infty$).  Therefore there must be an odd number of extrema.  It has to turnaround *at least* once (it goes down, hits a minimum then goes back up).  If it turns around twice then it would end up on the wrong side of $\infty$ so if it turns around again, it *must* turn around at least once more.  Look at this [sketch](http://sketchtoy.com/60254416) which shows several possibilities, one of which shows an inflection point where the derivative might go to zero but *not* be an extremum.  You should be able to show that there could not possibly be any inflection points since the second derivative will be $f''(x) = e^{|x|}$ which can never equal zero so there are no inflection points (the negative derivative will end up positive just like the positive derivative).

Alright so lets start finding critical numbers--that's easy:

\begin{align}
e^{|x|} - m = 0 \rightarrow |x| = \ln(m) \rightarrow m > 1 && x > 0 \\
-e^{|x|}  -m = 0 \rightarrow e^{|x|} = -m \rightarrow |x| = \ln(-m) \rightarrow x = -\ln(-m)\rightarrow m < -1 && x < 0
\end{align}

Alright, let's be careful because $x = 0$, where the derivative is undefined (jump discontinuity), is *also* a critical point.  Is it a local extrema though?  Look at the values from each side:

\begin{align}
1 - m && x > 0 \\
-1 - m && x < 0
\end{align}

We need two cases:

1. $1 - m < 0$ and $-1 - m > 0$
  $$
  m > 1 \\
  m < -1
  $$

  This is not possible since $m$ cannot both be greater than $1$
  *and*
  less than $-1$.
2. $1 - m > 0$ and $-1 - m < 0$
  $$
  m < 1 \\
  m > -1
  $$

  This leads to $-1 < m < 1$.  In this case, the derivative goes from negative (when $x < 0$) to positive (when $x > 0$) and this is a local minimum.

If $-1 < m < 1$ then we get a local minimum at $x = 0$ and there is *no other* critical points (since there is no $x$ for which $|x| = \ln(\pm m)$ when $-1 < m < 1$).  If this minimum is negative, then this function dips below $0$ and thus there should be *exactly* two solutions to the original equation.  So plug in $x = 0$ and see what you get:

$$
f(0) = e^0 - m(0 + 1) = 1 - m \stackrel{?}{<} 0 \rightarrow m > 1
$$

This *isn't* in our range, so if $-1 < m < 1$ then there are no solutions to the original equation (it never dips below or touches $0$).  There are still *two* more cases we need to handle manually: $m = -1$ and $m = 1$.  When $m = 1$ we get:

$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases} e^{|x|} - 1 & x > 0 \\ -e^{|x|} - 1 & x < 0\end{cases}
$$

When $x = 0$ we get $-1 - 1 = -2$ from the left and $1 - 1 = 0$ from the right?  So does this switch sign?  Yes because if you increase $x$ a little then the right side will become positive (think about it).  So this is a local minimum.  When $m = -1$ we get:

$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases} e^{|x|} +1 & x > 0 \\ -e^{|x|} +1 & x < 0\end{cases}
$$

Now the left side is $0$ and the right side is positive.  Again, if you go a little to the left (more negative in $x$) then the left side will be negative and thus you, again, get a local minimum.  Let's check the values at each of these two points:

\begin{align}
f(0) = 1 - (0 + 1) = 0 && m = 1 \\
f(0) = 1 + (0 + 1) = 2 && m = -1
\end{align}

These won't work.  When $m = -1$ the minimum is positive and thus there are *no* solutions and when $m = 1$ there is only a single solutions ($x = 0$) because the minimum *is* zero and thus the *only* time the function touches $0$.

Finally let's look at the cases when $m < -1$ and when $m > 1$:

\begin{align}
f(\ln(m)) = m - m(\ln(m) + 1) && m > 1 \\
f(\ln(\alpha)) = \alpha + \alpha(-\alpha + 1) && m = -\alpha, \alpha > 1
\end{align}

For the first case ($m > 1$), we get $m(1 - \ln(m) - 1) < 0 \rightarrow -\ln(m) < 0$.  This is true for *all* $m > 1$.

For the second case ($m < -1$), we get $\alpha(1 - \ln(\alpha) + 1) < 0 \rightarrow 2 - \ln(\alpha) < 0$.  This gives $\ln(\alpha) > 2 \rightarrow \alpha > e^2$.

Therefore there will be *exactly* two solutions when $m > 1$, exactly one solution when $m = 1$ (at $x = 0$), exactly one solution when $m = -e^2$ (at $x = -2$), exactly two solutions when $m < -e^2$, and no solutions otherwise.

So there will be exactly two solutions when $m < -e^2 \vee m > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not rigorous, but to get some general idea sketch your functions. Obviously, you get different lines by varying $m$, but all of them pass through $(-1,0)$ point. Main idea here is  to find such a line, when it's tangent to the exponential function.

[image: test]

Consider two situations separately, $x \ge 0$ and $x < 0$. To find $m$ for $x \ge 0$, solve system of equations
$$
l_1(x_0) = l_2(x_0) \\
l_1'(x_0) = l_2'(x_0)
$$
where $l_1(x) = e^x$ and $l_2(x) = m(x+1)$. You can easily find the solution here $x_0 = 0$ and $m = 1$. For any $m > 1$ line will cross the exponent twice.

Now,  consider $x < 0$. In that case $l_1(x) = e^{-x}$. Again, solving easy system reveals that $x_0 = -2$ and $m = -e^2$. For all $m < -e^2$ line will cross left part of the function twice.

Final answer is a union of above two sets. $m \in (-\infty, -e^2) \cup (1, +\infty)$.